# Rails how to implement html template to rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

Hi Im new to rails and wondering how actually rails developer implement html template to rails application. For example I want to use this template: [dashgum admin template](http://www.blacktie.co/2014/07/dashgum-free-dashboard/).

I end up copying the `css` and `js` files one by one to each responsible folder on *app/assets* and load it on `application.css` and `application.js` like this:

**application.css**

```
/*
 * ======================
 * Dashgum admin Template
 * ======================
 *
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require zabuto_calendar
 *= require jquery.gritter
 *= require line-icons-style
 *= require style
 *= require style-responsive
 */
```

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require Chart
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery-1.8.3.min
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require bootstrap-inputmask.min
//= require jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7
//= require jquery.scrollTo.min
//= require jquery.nicescroll
//= require jquery.sparkline
//= require jquery.tagsinput
//= require common-scripts
//= require jquery.gritter
//= require gritter-conf
//= require sparkline-chart
//= require zabuto_calendar
//= require products
//= require_self
```

I feel this is not a best practice / rails elegant way to do it. I wonder how you guys implement it? thanks for help.

**NOTE:** I don't wanna use gem like `install_theme` which is confusing a newbie like me

Answer (score 0):

Many popular libraries are available in rails packages such as [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

Add the gem to the `Gemfile` and you can do.

```
//= require bootstrap
```

In your css and js files.

The big advantage is that you don't have a bunch of vendor files littering your repository and that upgrading is somewhat easier.

However in many cases it may be better to [load popular libraries from CDNs](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) rather than have them moshed up in `application.js`

You could do something like the following if you want to use the sprockets pipeline in development and use fast CDNs for production:

1. Create a file named `app/assets/javascripts/development.js`. Don't require it from application.js.
2. Use a conditional in your layout

---

```
if Rails.env.production?
  javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
else
  javascript_include_tag "development"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment right now, but your (papirtiger) 'conditional in your layout' propose is painful. How do you imagine a production app which always will check that if statement? It's a bad code smell.

Answer (score -1):

I used to implement templates very similar as you shown above. I include every css files in application.css. In application.js I include most common files for all application, files which are needed for a single views I add by calling 'content_for' function in concrete view (and render them at the bottom of html document). Good practice is to create a 'plugins' directory in your assets folder and place there all plugins attached to template (you will need to add a 'plugins' directory to your assets path).

Sum of all, I think your solution is not to bad ;)

Comment: Good practice is to place 3rd party assets in `/vendor/assets` not `/app/assets`